# How do 2>r and 2r> work?

Tags: forth, gforth

Recently, on [comp.lang.forth](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.forth/gBXAQ30WSmg/7ZAKq3kFaCUJ) I found some code, kindly written by Coos Haak, which I have difficulty understanding.

It is supposed to sum or multiply the digits between the parenthesis. For example,

```
( 1 2 3 +)  ok
. 6  ok
```

For convenience, I'll reproduce it here:

```
: ( 
   depth 1+ r> 2>r 
; 

: cond 
   depth j > 
; 

: done 
   2r> rdrop 2>r 
; 

: +) 
   begin   cond 
   while   + 
   repeat 
   done 
; 

: *) 
   begin   cond 
   while   * 
   repeat 
   done 
;
```

I see the phrases `r> 2>r` and `2r> rdrop 2>r`. But, I'm rather confused about what they are doing. I'd guess that the stack depth at the open parenthesis is being hidden on the return stack somehow. But, I don't get it.

What do these do to the return stack?

In the Gforth documentation I see:

```
r>        R:w – w        core           “r-from”
2>r       d – R:d        core-ext       “two-to-r”
2r>       R:d – d        core-ext       “two-r-from”
rdrop     R:w –          gforth         “rdrop”

w  Cell, can contain an integer or an address 
d  double sized signed integer
```

Does this have something to do with the conversion between w and d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`2>r` (and the Forth 200x word [`n>r`](http://www.forth200x.org/n-to-r.html)) preserves the order of the elements pushed to the return stack.  So if the you have `( 1 0 )` on the data stack, with 0 as the top of the stack, then after `2>r` you will have 0 at the top of the return stack and 1 below it.  `2>r` is therefore definable, not as

```
: 2>r  ]] >r >r [[ ; immediate
```

But as:

```
: 2>r  ]] swap >r >r [[ ; immediate
```

And these definitions are equivalent:

```
: a  ]] 0 >r 1 >r [[ ; immediate
: b  ]] 0 1 2>r [[ ; immediate
```

What Coos Haak does in that code then is to slip a value below the top of the return stack.  If his `(` merely pushed the depth to the top of the return stack, then on exit from this word, gforth would try to jump to the depth as an address.  The same error condition is seen if you try to use his words in this way:

```
: numbers  ( 1 2 ; 
: sum  +) ;
numbers sum
\ output: :16: error: Invalid memory address
\         >>>numbers<<< sum
```

That code would work however (and the normal usage would fail) if `(` and `+)` coordinated with the third element on the return stack instead of the second.

There are a few pitfalls with this code:

1. The normal denizens of the return stack, so to speak, aren't guaranteed to take up only one cell of the return stack.
2. The use of `j` relies on knowledge about the precise depth into the return stack that `j` pulls from - i.e., it relies on knowledge about how `DO ... LOOP` and related words are implemented.

These words could be portably implemented as immediate words, where they would keep depth at the top of the return stack, but then you couldn't use them outside of a definition.  It's simple enough to make them work as is on any given Forth.

Comment: So, I guess in the gforth docs, a 'd' datatype is represented with two data elements and 'w' is with only one.  I'm glad to have the 200x reference now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical example of premature optimisation.
2>R moves two items to the return stack, but the standard prescribes the order that the two items arrive there. Coos Haak knows this and takes "advantage" of it.

Replace the code with the equivalent

```
 : ( 
   R>    \ remember return address
   depth >R
   >R    \ restore return address.
;
```

Now you see what is going on. You want to remember the stack depth, but if it is on the stack it will interfere with the calculation. So you tuck it under the return address of the **(** code, later to be retrieved in a similar fashion.

Alternatively you could make this a machine code definition and then there would not be a return address to worry about.

```
CODE (
   <DEPTH>  <to-r>
ENDCODE
```

where the actual machine code is left as an exercise.

Yet an other alternative is using a macro, that also need not worry about the return stack.

```
: (  POSTPONE DEPTH  POSTPONE >R  ;
```

I ignored the **1+** . Is a techicality, because **depth** itself changes the **depth** by 1. So you always have to judiciously add **1-**'s or **1+**'s whenever you actually use **depth** .